# How can I change a string into new string if it has any placeholders with square brackets inside curly brackets in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I get value for parameterisedString from database and parameterisedString contains some placeholders with no square brackets inside curly bracket e.g {Group} and some placeholders with square brackets inside curly brackets e.g {termMonth [month]} in the same string.

Example:
**parameterisedString='{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth [month]} - {termOdometer [kms]} {[$] DeductibleAmount [version]} {DeductibleType}';**

Placeholder with just curly bracket(e.g {Group}) doesn’t need to be replaced or changed but every Placeholder with square bracket inside curly bracket (e.g {termMonth [month]}) should be converted into {termMonth} placeholder and the text inside square bracket should be passed to getTranslation function to get Translation for that word and should not be interpolated .
e.g {termMonth [month]} : {termMonth} should be replaced or changed  to {termMonth} and “month” should be replaced with Translation for that word.

The desired should be now:
parameterisedString = '{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth} mois - {termOdometer} kms USD$ {DeductibleAmount} couverture {DeductibleType}';

```js
buildTitle(dealProduct: DealProductModel, tittleSuffix: boolean = false) {
    //Example:
    let parameterisedString='{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth [month]} - {termOdometer [kms]} {[$] DeductibleAmount [version]} {DeductibleType}';

    const pairs = [
        ['{Group}', `${dealProduct.name}`],
        ['{Desc}', `${dealProduct.coverageName}`],
        ['{termMonth}', `${dealProduct.termMonths}`],
        ['{termOdometer}', `${dealProduct.termOdometer.toLocaleString()}`],
        ['{DeductibleAmount}', `${dealProduct.deductibleAmount} Deductible`],
        ['{DeductibleType}', `${dealProduct.deductibleType}`]
      ];
              
      //HERE I NEED the changed parameterisedString and it should have all the words translated in square brackets before I interpolate. The desired should be now:     
      
      parameterisedString = '{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth} mois - {termOdometer} kms USD$ {DeductibleAmount} couverture {DeductibleType}';
      
      // interpolate the string
        let key, val;
        for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
          [key, val] = pairs[i];
          parameterisedString = parameterisedString.replace(`${key}`, `${val}`);
        }

    return parameterisedString;
  }


getTranslation(word: string) {  
    -----
    -----
    return  TranslatedWord; 
}
```

the desired should be now:
**parameterisedString = '{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth} mois - {termOdometer} kms USD$ {DeductibleAmount} couverture {DeductibleType}';**

Comment: why is `[$]` at the beginning of the `{wordHere}` while all other `[textHere]` is after the curly bracket words

Comment: I am basically making key value in my pairs array which will replace in my interpolate loop. I am using $ to make it template literal for every pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to find all occurrences of {TERM}, then split it and if the word starts with '[' replace it with the translation if not return it between {}

```js
function changeTemplate(template) {
    return template.replace(/{(.*?)}/g, (match, template) => {
        return template.split(/\s+/).map(word => {
            return word.startsWith('[') ? getTranslation(word.slice(1, -1)) : `{${word}}`
        }).join(' ');
    })
}


// mock translation
const translations = {
    month: 'mois',
    kms: 'kms',
    $: 'USD$',
    version: 'couverture'
};

function getTranslation(string) {
    return translations[string] || string;
}


let parameterisedString='{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth [month]} - {termOdometer [kms]} {[$] DeductibleAmount [version]} {DeductibleType}';


console.log(changeTemplate(parameterisedString));
```

Comment: sney2002 you are the man. Just one question if API team sends comma inside {[$] , DeductibleAmount , [version]}then how can we get the result like this: USD$ {DeductibleAmount} couverture?

Comment: @KarimAli You can change the regex to include the comma, then remove any empty string:
 template.split(/\s+|,/).filter(word => word.trim()).map(SAME_CODE...)

Answer (score 0):

for the specific `{DeductibleAmount} {[$] DecuctibleType [coverage]}` isn't `{DeductibleAmount [$]} {DeductibleType [coverage]}` like in the format for the rest of the string.. however if the format is constant.. I have your answer

```js
let parameterisedString = '{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth [month]} - {termOdometer [kms]} {DeductibleAmount [$]} {DeductibleType [coverage]}'

pm=parameterisedString.split('')
var arr=[]
let translate=arrOfText=>arrOfText //receives an array of text that would have spacebar then the characters of a term in square bracket.. for example, [" ","m","o","n","t","h"]
while(pm.includes('[')&&pm.includes(']')){
  var curlyVar=pm.splice(0,pm.indexOf('[')-1)
  curlyVar.push('}')
  var bracketVar=pm.splice(pm.indexOf('[')-1,pm.indexOf(']')+2)
  bracketVar.splice(1,1)
  bracketVar.splice(bracketVar.length-2,2)
  bracketVar=translate(bracketVar) //here is where you can translate the value eg [" ","m","o","n","t","h"] to [" ","m","o","i","s"]
  arr=arr.concat(curlyVar)
  arr=arr.concat(bracketVar)
}
parameterisedString=arr.join('')
console.log(parameterisedString)
```

However, with your string, the layout looks SLIGHTLY different.. work in progress

```js
let parameterisedString = '{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth [month]} - {termOdometer [kms]} {DeductibleAmount} {[$] DeductibleType [coverage]}'

pm=parameterisedString.split('')
var arr=[]
let translate=arrOfText=>arrOfText //receives an array of text that would have spacebar then the characters of a term in square bracket.. for example, [" ","m","o","n","t","h"]
while(pm.includes('[')&&pm.includes(']')){
  var curlyVar=pm.splice(0,pm.indexOf('[')-1)
  curlyVar.push('}')
  var bracketVar=pm.splice(pm.indexOf('[')-1,pm.indexOf(']')+2)
  bracketVar.splice(1,1)
  bracketVar.splice(bracketVar.length-2,2)
  bracketVar=translate(bracketVar) //here is where you can translate the value eg [" ","m","o","n","t","h"] to [" ","m","o","i","s"]
  arr=arr.concat(curlyVar)
  arr=arr.concat(bracketVar)
}
parameterisedString=arr.join('')
console.log(parameterisedString)
```

Comment: {DeductibleAmount} isn't {DeductibleAmount [$]}. DeductibleType has 2 values to be translated. [$] and [coverage]

Comment: i see. i'll try to change it so the code works

Comment: @KarimAli do tell me what's the logic in putting [$] to the left and [coverage] to the right.. is it because they're to the left and right of the word?

Comment: {[$] DeductibleType [coverage]} means [$] should be translated, DeductibleType should be interpolated and [coverage] should be translated. The whole parameterisedString comes from database based on some rules for each product.

Comment: ok let me clarify my question.. everything inside the curly brackets has the square bracket content to the RIGHT eg `{termMonth [month]}` to `{termMonth} month` now my question is why does `{[$] DeductibleType [coverage]}` become `$ {DeductibleType} coverage` AND NOT `{DeductibleType} $ coverage`

Comment: i repeat: my question is why does `{[$] DeductibleType [coverage]}` become `$ {DeductibleType} coverage` AND NOT `{DeductibleType} $ coverage`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my string: it should be parameterisedString='{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth [month]} - {termOdometer [kms]} {[$] DeductibleAmount [version]} {DeductibleType}'; {[$] DeductibleAmount [version]} has 2 values to be translated and DeductibleAmount should be interpolated. Sorry I apologize for the mistake. Since DeductibleAmount is amount we are displaying USD$ {DeductibleAmount}'s value and  couverture.

Comment: The Bomb Squad : thanks for trying. Appreciated.